# AD/DC, DNS and DHCP on Hyper-V host

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, hyper-v, dhcp-server, windows-server-2019

I'm trying to set up AD/DC with DNS (reverse lookup zone) and DHCP on single Hyper-V host. [Network diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZAGU.jpg)

On the diagram is pretty everything I've set, the rest should be on default, however I'm obviously missing something because non of the devices can grab DHCP settings from that server. There is no Address Lease, no new device in AD, nothing. 
I'm using MikroTik router, where DHCP is disabled.
However when I turn on DHCP on the router, it detects connected devices, and they immediately get IP settings and have access to the internet.
Is there any obvious issue on the first sight?

Comment: Firewall? If the DHCP is on a vm - DHCP guard on that machine.

Comment: Is this just for testing?

Comment: I'm trying to apply this scheme to the small business environment.
Will check firewall settings later, first will try to apply joeqwertys suggestion

Comment: Do not dual-home your Domain Controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Your DHCP Scope is configured for the ip address space for the virtual NIC that's bound to a Private virtual switch (based on your having the word Private in parentheses next to the Internal NIC). Is that a Private virtual switch? If so, Private virtual switches only allow for communication between VM's that are bound to the same Private virtual switch. Private virtual switches do not allow for communication between the VM and the physical network.

Why does the DC have two virtual network interfaces? Why are you using a DHCP assigned ip address on the virtual NIC connected to the External Virtual switch?

If it were me, I'd remove the virtual NIC connected to the Private virtual switch, I'd remove the Private virtual switch, and then I'd assign 10.250.26.12 to the virtual NIC that's connected to the External virtual switch.

Comment: As you recomended, Private virtual switch is disabled:
![Valid XHTML](https://prnt.sc/pnm91x).
Still, user devices do not get IP configuration from the DHCP at all. 
However, when I do set IP configuration manually on the device ( ![Valid XHTML](https://prnt.sc/po1vad). ), I can finally reach domain controller and add device to the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I disabled Private virtual switch ( [Single virtual interface](https://prnt.sc/pnm91x) ) but user devices still do not get IP configuration from the DHCP at all. However, when I set up IP configuration manually on the device ( [Manual IP config](https://prnt.sc/po1vad) ), I can at least reach domain controller and add device to the domain. 
What could I possibly overlook?